# View won't show when layout is inflated

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

Here's my list_section.xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
android:background="@color/colorBackgroundDark"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewAssessmentTypeName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#8000FF00" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm inflating it in my RecyclerViewAdapter through:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    ...
    else if (viewType == TYPE_SECTION) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_section, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolderSection(view, callback);
    } 
    ...
}

private class ViewHolderSection extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {
    ItemClickListener callback;
    TextView assessmentTypeName;

    ViewHolderSection(View view, ItemClickListener callback) {
        super(view);
        this.callback = callback;
        assessmentTypeName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewAssessmentTypeName);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        view.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onItemLongClick(getAdapterPosition());
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

But for some reason the View in layout.xml, which I'm using as a color filter/overlay over RelativeLayout won't show. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing list_section.xml to:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:background="@color/colorBackgroundDark">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewAssessmentTypeName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#8000FF00" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

the previous one didn't work because the layout_height of RelativeLayout ended up being 0.